# Binding class not resolved after layout file name changed

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

I had a layout file named `activity_main.xml` and `binding` class was `ActivityMainBinding` but for some reason, I had to rename the layout file name to `activity_dashboard.xml`, after it shows the error can't resolve `ActivityMainBinding`.

Comment: yes because maybe somewhere in the code you are using name `ActivityMainBinding` maybe like `AcitiviMainBinding.inflate(inflater)` but now you have to say `ActivityDashBoardBinding.inflate()`

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan why I need to change that? if the class name changes when the layout file name changes, then why it is not changed at places where it is being referred?

Comment: that is something android studio developers should care about , all i know that data binding library generates binding class for each layout file in which you use tag `layout` by removing underscores if they exist and converting it to camel case and appending the work Binding to it, for now you have to change it everywhere if you change the layout file name

Comment: Try to rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

Build -> Clean project. After that close android studio. You'll see generated binding classes gone. Now you can use, ActivityDashboardBinding. After changes Build -> Make project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your layout has root as

```
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</layout>
```

And binding enabled:

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34697793)